# Eliminar símbolo porcentaje % de toda una base de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, porcentaje

Tengo una base de datos donde 8 columnas tiene el símbolo porcentaje.
¿ Cómo puedo quitar el valor % para todos los datos de estas 8 columnas ( 2 a 9 en python?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pues con una sentencia UPDATE con la clausula WHERE preguntando si esa columna es igual a ese carácter % o simplemente machacando su valor.

```
sql = "update fichero set columna1 = '' where fecha = '%'"
self.modelo.actualiza(sql,'')
def actualiza(self, sql, val):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql, val)
        self.db_registro = self.cursor.fetchone()
        self.db_rows = self.cursor.rowcount
        self.db.commit()
        if self.db_rows:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        self.db_sts_msg = e
        print(self.db_sts_msg)
        return False
```